# mensagem não sendo mostrada na tela com cout

Tags: c++

dando início aos meu estudos em c++, montei um simples código de um jogo da forca, segue código abaixo para exemplificação:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
int main(){
  int tam = 0, i = 0, chances = 6, acertos = 0;
  char palavra[30], secreta[30], letra[1];
  bool acerto = false;
  cout << "Informe a palavra: ";
  cin >> palavra;
  system("cls");
  for(int cont = 0; cont < 30; cont++) {
      secreta[cont] = '-';
  }

  while(palavra[i] != '\0') {
    tam++;
    i++;
  }

  while((chances > 0) && (acertos < tam)) {
    cout << "\nChances restantes: " << chances;
    cout << "\nPalavra secreta: "; 
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        cout << secreta[i];
    }
    cout << "\nInforme uma letra: ";
    cin >> letra[0];
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++){
      if(letra[0] == secreta[i]){
        cout << "letra já adicionada!";
        break;
      } else if (palavra[i] == letra[0]){
            acerto = true;
            secreta[i] = letra[0];
            acertos++;
        }
        
    }
    if(!acerto) {
        chances--;
    }
    acerto = false;
    system("cls");
  }
   if (acertos == tam){
    cout << "Parabéns, você ganhou!\n\n";
  } else {
    cout<< "Que pena, você perdeu!\n\n";
  }
  
    system("pause");
}
```

O código deu certo e tive o resultado esperado. Exceto pelo trecho:

```
for(i = 0; i < tam; i++){
      if(letra[0] == secreta[i]){
        cout << "letra já adicionada!";
        break;
```

Onde apesar do loop ser interrompido a mensagem "letra já adicionada" não é mostrada na tela.

O que fiz de errado?

Comment: Dica sobre o uso das tags na pergunta: se ela é spbre C++, use apenas a tag dessa linguagem. Não faz sentido marcá-la como Python se a pergunta não tem relação com essa linguagem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

esse seu código é quase todo da linguagem "C" , e pouca coisa de 'C++' , apenas o  "**cout <<**" e o **"cin >>"**, e
a msg está na tela sim , mas o "cls" limpa a tela em seguida .  e uma forma seria colocar uma temporização após a msg,

```
#include     <windows.h>
for(i = 0; i < tam; i++)
{
  if(letra[0] == secreta[i])
  {
    cout << "letra já adicionada!";
    Sleep(1000);
    break;
  }
}
```